# Choosing OS grub screen not displaying

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2, windows-7

I installed Windows 7 after Ubuntu 14.04. I recovery GRUB, but when I start system the Grub window where I need to choose the OS not display, and Ubuntu loads by default.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have it yet, install GRUB Customizer:

```
$sudo install grub-customizer
```

...and make sure that GRUB can see both OS's.  If it can, double-check the "General Settings" page.  In the "Advanced Settings" check the values of `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT`, `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET` and `GRUB_TIMEOUT`.

If `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT` is greater than zero, then GRUB is waiting (that many seconds) for a keypress to show the boot menu.  Also make sure that `GRUB_TIMEOUT` is greater than zero, so that the menu is visible for that many seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You need to boot an Ubuntu Live image from a DVD or USB drive, then use the chroot method to reinstall the bootloader. Follow these instructions and you should be good to go: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#via_ChRoot

To write the Ubuntu ISO image to a bootable USB stick in Windows you can use Win32DiskImager http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/files/latest/download or Universal USB Installer http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/